# How do I update minitoc

Tags: table-of-contents, packages, minitoc

I'm desperatly trying to update my minitocs I added in the beginning of every chapter. To do so, I've tried compiling several times, and I've tried to delete my "`\minitoc` and my `\dominitoc` in my code.

I've also deleted my `test.toc` file... And then adding back the code lines and compiling several times...
But nothing seems to work.

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% \usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=3.25cm, vmargin=4.5cm}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[francais]{minitoc}

\titleformat*{\subsection}{\large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\bfseries}
 \titleformat*{\paragraph}{\large\bfseries}
\captionsetup{figurewithin=none} 
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\title{Rapport}
\begin{figure}
 \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Illustrations/logoUM.png} % logo um
\hspace{0.05cm} % espace latéral
\includegraphics[scale=0.035]{Illustrations/logoINRA.jpg} % logo inra
\hspace{0.05cm} % espace latéral
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{Illustrations/logoMISTEA.png} % logo mistea
\end{figure}
\author{M G}
\date{1 février 2016 au 30 juin 2016}
\end{titlepage}

\maketitle

\include{Preface/remerciements}
\include{Preface/introduction}

\listoffigures
\tableofcontents
\dominitoc

\include{Contenu/presentation_entreprise}
...
\include{Contenu/rapport_activite}

\include{Annexe/conclusion}

\include{Annexe/bibliographie}
\include{Annexe/sitographie}
\include{Annexe/annexes}


\end{document}
```

And inside Contenu/presentation_entreprise:

```
\chapter{Présentation de la structure d'accueil}

\minitoc
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your document is not compilable. Please reduce it to the minimum version that is compilable and that shows the issue

Answer (score 1):

`\dominitoc` should be used before `\tableofcontents`, not after it!

There are also some issues (like the the `figure` environment within the titlepage (why?)) and `hyperref` should be loaded last (here!).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin=3.25cm, vmargin=4.5cm}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage[francais]{minitoc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\titleformat*{\subsection}{\large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\bfseries}
 \titleformat*{\paragraph}{\large\bfseries}
\captionsetup{figurewithin=none} 
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\title{Rapport}
\begin{figure}
 \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Illustrations/logoUM.png} % logo um
\hspace{0.05cm} % espace latéral
\includegraphics[scale=0.035]{Illustrations/logoINRA.jpg} % logo inra
\hspace{0.05cm} % espace latéral
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{Illustrations/logoMISTEA.png} % logo mistea
\end{figure}
\author{M G}
\date{1 février 2016 au 30 juin 2016}
\end{titlepage}



\maketitle

%\include{Preface/remerciements}
%\include{Preface/introduction}

\dominitoc

\listoffigures
\tableofcontents

\include{Contenu/presentation_entreprise}
%\include{Contenu/rapport_activite}

%\include{Annexe/conclusion}

%\include{Annexe/bibliographie}
%\include{Annexe/sitographie}
%\include{Annexe/annexes}


\end{document}
```

The `presentation_entreprise.tex` file:

```
\chapter{Présentation de la structure d'accueil}

\minitoc

\section{C'est perdu}

\blindtext
```

[image]